# HTML/CSS - comment box keeps overlapping with eachother in comment section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a comment box where a user can leave their username, rating for a product, and an actual comment.

I've attached my html, css, and javascript files below so that you can run the actual application. In the css file, this part:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align:left;
    width: 540px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

implements the width and height for each individual comment. The list-group class:

```
.list-group {
    height: 600px;
    width: 540px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

represents the entire comment section as a whole. I set it to a height of 600px so that if there are more than 3 comments / if the comments exceed 600px (each comment is 200px in height), then a scroll bar would appear so that the user can keep scrolling through the section to read comments. The problem is when I continue to keep adding comments, the height of each comment doesn't stay 200px and continues to shrink as more comments are added. I'm not sure why this is and would really appreciate some help.

This is what my comment section looks like with 4 comments vs a bunch of extra comments. As you can see, the individual comments just keep shrinking and shrinking.

[image]

[image]

```js
function todoList() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value
    var rating = document.getElementById("rating").value
    
    var userNameText = document.createTextNode("Username: " + username)
    var commentText = document.createTextNode("Comment: " + comment)
    var ratingText = document.createTextNode("Rating: " + rating + "/10")

    var newListItem = document.createElement("LI")
    newListItem.className = "list-group-item"
    var newRating = document.createElement("rating")
    newRating.appendChild(ratingText)
    var newUserName = document.createElement("username")
    newUserName.appendChild(userNameText)
    var newComment = document.createElement("comment")
    newComment.appendChild(commentText)

    newListItem.appendChild(newRating)
    newListItem.appendChild(newUserName)
    newListItem.appendChild(newComment)
    document.getElementById("reviewList").appendChild(newListItem)
}
```

```css
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    background-color: blue;
}

@keyframes type{ 
  from { width: 0; } 
} 

input {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* each comment box */
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align:left;
    width: 540px;
    height: 200px;
}

.rating, rating {
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

.username, username {
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 40px;
}

comment {
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 70px;
}

#formcontrol {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.list-group {
    height: 600px;
    width: 540px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="t3.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="container">
        <label for="ratingLabel">Choose a rating:</label>
        <select name="rating" id="rating">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <form id="todoForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" style="font-size: 20px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="comment" style="font-size: 20px;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" onclick="todoList()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">click me</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <ul id="reviewList" class="list-group">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="t3.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a global variable outside of the todoList function. `let counter = 1`
At the bottom of that function, the last line of that function will be `counter++`. Add this logic in the beginning of the function:

```
var height = (counter*200).toString() + "px"
document.getElementById("review-list").style.height = height;
```

This will simply increase the height of your ul by 200px every nth component. And finally remove the height component from your css in the list-group class. You could make the ul element disappear until there is an input. for this add the attribute in the css to list-group `visibility: hidden;` and add logic to the function:
`if(counter === 1) {document.getElementById("review-list").style.visibility="visible"}`

There is a different solution that is easier. If you would like the ul to stay the same size, but would like to scroll, simply change overflow to scroll.

```
.list-group {
  height:600px;
  width:560px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

when overflow is auto it clumps the content together to fit it all on the screen.